# What's the base value of Attribute Thresholds?

Tags: character-creation, mechwarrior-3e

Mechwarrior 3rd Edition starts the buying of stats on page 56, after one is through the lifepath. It begins somewhat neat:

> The cost of an attribute depends on its Attribute threshold determined through the Life Path and your character's Age (see *Age*, p.60).

Now, Page 60 lists a table with modifications based on the age, but no base numbers.

So, let's just look at one attribute for our example assuming Luke was born in the Outworld Alliance and took Farm (1) and Farm (2), he gets a Threshold of Strength +1 from Farm (1) and nothing from Farm (2) and being 16. The result is... uh...

**Where** is the *base number* to which the Attribute Threshold modifiers from the lifepath and age are applied to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The organization of the chapter isn't actually the best, as the answer is actually *way before* the calculation step or even the first step of character generation:

When attributes were introduced on Page 22, pointing to page 56 to calculate them, the relevant Keyword of the Attribute Threshold was only introduced on page 23, including the base number to which the modifiers are added. There is no reference back to this crucial little sentence on page 56 or 60, where one gets the modifiers from. The two crucial lines in the paragraph are:

> All Attributes begin with a threshold of 6 except of Edge, which begins with a Threshold of 8
>
> An Attribute threshold can not drop below 2 or increase higher than 10. Disregard modifiers that exceed these limits.

As a result, Luke, the Farmer from the Outworld Alliance, has a Strenght Threshold of 6+1=7.